# How can i store the input without using array?

Tags: c++, loops, input, aabb

The question required to compute a minimum-sized AABB for a set of input geometries.

The types of geometries are listed below:

1. Rectangle , center_x , center_y, width , height : R x y w h
2. Circle, center_x, center_y, radius : C x y r
3. Set of points, number of points, x_1, y_1 , ... , x_n , y_n : P n x_1 y_1 ... x_n y_n
4. **#** : indicates end of input

---

The sample case are shown below:

input:

R 0 0 3 2
#

output:

0 0 3 2

input:

P 2 3 -2 -1 4

C -0.5 3.2 1.6

P 3 -1.5 3 3 3 5 3

R 0 0 3 2

#

output:

1.45 1.4 7.1 6.8

---

I am wondering about how the sample case two run, as there are multi-input, how can I construct my AABB? However, how to avoid the situation that the variable being replace?

For example,

R 0 0 3 2

R 1 2 4 5

I just don't know how to avoid the replacement of the center_x, center_y , w and h.

---

below are my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int times, i;
    char geo;
    double center_x, center_y, w, h, r;
    double box_LX = 0, box_RX = 0, box_DY = 0, box_UY = 0;
    bool end;
    end = false;
    double LX, RX, UY, DY;


    while (!end) {
        cin >> geo;
        if (geo == 'R') {
            cin >> center_x >> center_y >> w >> h;
            LX = (center_x - w / 2);
            RX = (center_x + w / 2);
            DY = (center_y - h / 2);
            UY = (center_y + h / 2);
            if (RX > box_RX)
                box_RX = RX;
            if (LX < box_LX)
                box_LX = LX;
            if (UY > box_UY)
                box_UY = UY;
            if (DY < box_DY)
                box_DY = DY;
        }
        if (geo == 'C') {
            cin >> center_x >> center_y >> r;
            if (box_RX < (center_x + r))
                box_RX = center_x + r;
            if (box_LX > (center_x - r))
                box_LX = center_x - r;
            if (box_UY < (center_y + r))
                box_UY = center_y + r;
            if (box_DY < (center_y - r))
                box_DY = center_y - r;
        }
        if (geo == 'P') {
            cin >> times;
            i = 0;
            while (i != times) {
                cin >> center_x >> center_y;
                if (box_RX < center_x)
                    box_RX = center_x;
                if (box_LX > center_x)
                    box_LX = center_x;
                if (box_UY < center_y)
                    box_UY = center_y;
                if (box_DY > center_y)
                    box_DY = center_y;
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (geo == '#') {
            cout << (box_LX+box_RX)/2 << " " << (box_DY+box_UY)/2 << " " << abs(box_LX - box_RX) << " " << abs(box_UY - box_DY) << endl;
            end = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I  think it's kind of hard you do that without using arrays. You should use it if you wanna multiple inputs into yout program

Comment: All you should need is the last box (which is the minimum box containing all previous shapes) and the next shape. With these you can calculate what the next minimum box should be. At the end of the input you print out these dimensions.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using arrays?   Note that "I don't understand how to use arrays" is not a reason - because, although it takes a little effort, it is worth learning how to use arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an array for this. As an analogy, imagine you are instead trying to find the minimum int from a list of ints (which is similar to what you're doing, but in one dimension instead of two). All you need to keep track of the minimum value is

1. The current minimum of all previous values (`current`), and
2. The next value (`value`).

From those two values you can calculate the next minimum - `min(current, value)`, then grab the next value, calculate the minimum again, and so on. At the end of the input print out `current`. At no point do you need to store *all* values at once.

For your question, replace `current` with the current minimum-sized AABB, `value` with the next shape, and `min` with a function that returns the minimum-sized AABB that contains both shapes.

[image]

In this image, you have 2 previous shapes (the 2 black boxes), the current minimum (the gray box), the next shape (the blue circle), and the next minimum (the red box) that you need to calculate, which contains both the gray box and the blue circle.

Comment: how about if the geometries is not overlapping? I think we can't just " replace " the value

Comment: My analogy isn't perfect. If they don't entirely overlap then the minimum AABB will have to expand to fit everything.

Comment: I added a picture to help explain it better

Comment: Thanks! I know the logic behind, but I just no idea how can I " store " the point in order to  " compare " its x, y value respectively. Would you feel free to give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can already store a box and a circle as shown in the code in your question. A point is just an x and y pair. Note that for points you just need to store one at a time - you can expand the minimum AABB as you read them in.

Comment: I edited my code, I pass some test case but i dont know why when I put 3 points instead of 2 will lead to failed....